# Where to ask: given an audio file, which song is playing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have an audio file and famous software like Shazam to detect which music is playing gives "no result", that's not a problem of quality of the file, it's surely because the song isn't in the Shazam database. The audio file is the sound of a video on a Social Media post.

So I wonder if there is a Stack Exchange website where I could ask for some help to find which song this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Music Fans Stack Exchange](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com) has an entire tag dedicated to these questions: [identify-this-song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-song). It's even their [top tag](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tags/).

> For questions looking to identify a song. Be sure to include enough information (lyric snippets, a good quality sound clip, etc.) for someone to be able to identify it.

This is one of the few cases where a question doesn't need to be self-contained, a link to the video should suffice.

Comment: Thank you! Does it work if the link is a Facebook url?

Comment: If it's publicly accessible, yes. Many people (including me) don't have a Facebook account. You might want to rehost it somewhere else (YouTube) if the license allows it.

Comment: Facebook pics and videos are usually accessible, as far as I can tell. e.g. [this video](https://www.facebook.com/MeowTVPage/videos/410369993024713/) can be viewed without FB account, and pretty sure audio files and pictures follow same pattern.